# Making a custom table from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is called Storage_Tot which has **date, tagid, value** components.

Below are the two tables (Table A and Table B) I created using SQL query. I essentially ran same query with different tagid with the same table 'Storage_Tot). I would like to combine table A and B and also add a 3rd column which is the sum of the values of Table A and Table B (Table C).

Table A (Left table) Table B (Right Table)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y5Xo.png)

Here is the sample query that I wrote for the two tables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etnSH.png)

This is how I would like my final table to look like. As a first step I was trying to just combine the the values of Table A and Table B and after that focus on the arithmetic aspect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzaAU.png)

Here is the SQL query when combing the two tables but it does not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMtFG.png)

_______________________________________ APPEND

Since I couldn't post under the response question, After implementing your suggestion here is the error that I get. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAtxO.png)

This is how the query looks as it sits and it appears that its not like where Storage_Tot.TagID = 106

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADEYJ.png)

Comment: Add the code to the post. Is it MySQL or SQL? You used both tags

Comment: @rhand - what's wrong with using both `mysql` and `sql` tags?  SQL is definitely one key aspect of using MySQL, but someone might instead have a question about MySQL administration, or performance, etc.

Comment: it is best to provide what can be text *as* text, right in the body of your question; your example query could certainly be in your question; output from your query, too -- just enough rows to illustrate your question;  see SO's page on making a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for is (1) a `JOIN` and (2) a calculated column.

Here's the general idea for a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    tblA.date, tblA.value, tblB.value
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM Storage_Tot WHERE tagid = 'TABLEA_TAGID') tblA
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM Storage_Tot WHERE tagid = 'TABLEB_TAGID') tblB
ON (tblA.date = tblB.date);
```

Some of that is guesswork, because you [didn't provide complete details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.  But hopefully you can see what's going on: the sub-queries in a way 'create' what you are calling the two tables shown in your first image.

Now, to add a total, just add a calculated column to the above query:

```
SELECT
    tblA.date, tblA.value, tblB.value, tblA.value + tblB.value AS total_value
```

<s>I have not verified any of this in an instance of MySQL, but I do believe I have the syntax correct for MySQL.  You might need to make small adjustments for typos.</s>.  I have verified the above syntax via SQL Fiddle.  Of course you need to fill in what `TABLEA_TAGID` and `TABLEB_TAGID` really are.

There are also lots of tutorials and references for using `JOIN`s on-line.  There are various kinds of `JOIN`s, and I'm only showing one kind here.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I am getting this weird error

Comment: I am having issues posting my message here especially when I try insert snip shots of query. I will try it again.. Please bare with me..

Comment: @FaisalShibli  I think you'll have an easier time pasting them in as updates to your question; there is more room, and there are more options for markdown / formatting;  try that;  I'm off-line for a bit, but I'll check back later

Comment: I have added notes after APPEND section in my original post.

Comment: @FaisalShibli  re: the error message you added, at the place where you have "... from Storage_Tot.Tag_ID = 107 ..." you need "... from Storage_Tot WHERE Storage_Tot.Tag_ID = 107 ..."  -- also check your "a" table sub-query for the same thing

Comment: It doesn't allow me to mark it as correct answer because I am still a new member. Are you able to do it on my behalf.

Comment: @FaisalShibli  I'm not able to accept an answer on your behalf -- I don't think anyone is;  my understanding is that being a new member does not prevent you from accepting another user's answer to your own question;  what happens when you click on the grey checkmark on the left next to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

@landru27: Thank you so much for your help. I don't know how I missed that from/where syntax. Anyway, I took your direction and had to make minor changes and the code executed. 
Below is the final code that I shall be using for my query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x04q.png)

Comment: I'm very glad I helped solve your problem, and I'm happy to lend a hand;  please consider marking my answer as the accepted answer; it lets others see that it works as a solution to the question you had in case they have a similar question, and awards me a small amount of StackOverflow reputation; thanks!